# Apt-get package depends on itself (filebeat)

Tags: 14.04, apt

I have multiple servers with Ubuntu 14.04 and installed filebeat on every machine except one, and I can't figure out how to fix it actually. but the package depends on it self.

I tried to install filebeat with the docs side by side 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/setup-repositories.html

I have run `apt-get clean` I removed the PGP key, i remove the entry from sources.list with `apt-get update` etc and even tried a reboot.

But I keep getting the following message

```
sudo apt-get install filebeat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package filebeat is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'filebeat' has no installation candidate
```

When running `apt-cache depends|rdepends` I get the dependency result which is strange.

```
apt-cache depends filebeat
<filebeat>
apt-cache rdepends filebeat
<filebeat>
```

So it seems that the package depends on itself. and the package is virtual (so the questions is how do I remove a virtual package from apt-cache?).

The server is not running in production and can be rebuild. But I just want to know what happend here and how to solve it.

```
apt-cache show filebeat
Package: filebeat
Version: 1.1.2
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@b57f031fe36a>
Installed-Size: 13229
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.1.2_amd64.deb
Size: 4118402
SHA1: f0da23647e41e1cca2eb6f7125d07f522f449f40
SHA256: e5c4787ff9ba000944b2776a6278aa7b94c66e4bb51e85baa53cf41bf1dd60f7
MD5sum: 2d8a5287ddf236d758150c9e5e3d8942
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.1.1
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@d1eb38ab66ca>
Installed-Size: 13235
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.1.1_amd64.deb
Size: 4119868
SHA1: c6f0646a479d95b83ef49bcbeda03fde85f1639c
SHA256: bdc0720e98b64a9516bbca3e8a0dfa8e8c8147a5fc97c3201d74fa6e102e9f37
MD5sum: 545dc9e3de9dbbaafb114a9229116e5a
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.1.0
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@8aac0fd97093>
Installed-Size: 13234
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.1.0_amd64.deb
Size: 4119754
SHA1: 3e3a58fda637a17cf6b32e6a4e549b05f4bceea0
SHA256: 22408b623e45231d8262adc9d41a18650a7fdd2d859c869351d6d67d3c9c4eef
MD5sum: 328482edcc47f8fc1a81e96e725d68a1
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.0.1
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@56e955b2dd7c>
Installed-Size: 11845
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.0.1_amd64.deb
Size: 3749796
SHA1: b2f4b6cf4766ebdd97046985130ba4530033d879
SHA256: 368ebfafa1561997e5a567bc76fd127c6e4411d3f13a65ed8de41c22a775a4b5
MD5sum: 96add296e0fa1456ece0283cbe065c24
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.0.0
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@cef0f1166e5c>
Installed-Size: 11676
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.0.0_amd64.deb
Size: 3744762
SHA1: c61b4d1a661daab1892afe7ac98474b16015de25
SHA256: c53255bdabc30d21a55010b4221e2ec8d6c47cf7288151a258056d50b4972c76
MD5sum: d0dc1c15e06d116636565dc0c22abd69
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.0.0~rc2
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@fceab8a8bd91>
Installed-Size: 11672
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.0.0-rc2_amd64.deb
Size: 3741714
SHA1: 3a7123d7ae8a1ce9ebdf117fb5fa9c84d1dc31a8
SHA256: 2eb7e05700da4147142a2688745089f9cec2e0d4040ecdf783c19a6612b15851
MD5sum: dbf35ff8fae3f83211cb968cdf6ca115
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.0.0~rc1
License: ASL 2.0
Vendor: Elastic
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@46232e7f7a75>
Installed-Size: 11545
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.0.0-rc1_amd64.deb
Size: 3709604
SHA1: 00d8eabf3bf9701bf9d4505d1fb38e34b4287e2f
SHA256: f4f21d4fbc1b2a9608529dff0302b1840d5dc00aeb84dbf03be70b3ab317580c
MD5sum: 860347bae403c66e6e0817bd294865c1
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

Package: filebeat
Version: 1.0.0~beta4
License: unknown
Vendor: @5665a3fc341b
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: <@5665a3fc341b>
Installed-Size: 10916
Section: default
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://github.com/elastic/filebeat
Filename: pool/f/fi/filebeat_1.0.0-beta4_amd64.deb
Size: 3550610
SHA1: 0e115e2a6faa102bd4d4f76585e9498280271acc
SHA256: ef3ee567f3cec012a2aeef4db37132b08d7876c4802a771d7efcbfd06d883609
MD5sum: 3d366448b82f5e71360e9b0f627e366a
Description: Sends log files to Logstash or directly to Elasticsearch.
Description-md5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d
```

And

```
apt-cache showpkg filebeat
Package: filebeat
Versions: 
1.1.2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.1.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.1.0 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.0.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.0.0 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.0.0~rc2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.0.0~rc1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d

1.0.0~beta4 (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d


Reverse Depends: 
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
  filebeat:i386,filebeat
Dependencies: 
1.1.2 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.1.1 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.1.0 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.0.1 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.0.0 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.0.0~rc2 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.0.0~rc1 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
1.0.0~beta4 - filebeat:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
1.1.2 - 
1.1.1 - 
1.1.0 - 
1.0.1 - 
1.0.0 - 
1.0.0~rc2 - 
1.0.0~rc1 - 
1.0.0~beta4 - 
Reverse Provides
```

`dpkg -l` gives me nothing

Installing the package from the `.deb` file works flawless, after remove/purge of the package still the same error in `apt-get`

Is it possible that the dependencies are resolved incorrectly somehow on that machine?

Comment: `filebeat` looks like a Virtual package, and that basically means that `filebeat` is provided by other packages (with a `Provides: filebeat` line in their `debian/control` for the built binary package).  The problem is, this isn't in the Ubuntu repositories - there's no way to determine what actually *provides* the `filebeat` package.

Comment: I can check all other packages that are installed on that machine but not on the others

Comment: Didn't found a solution :(

Comment: Is there a filebeat:i386 installed maybe (try removing it)?

Comment: @JanC No, couldn't find any filebeat package installed searched everywhere. also i reinstalled it from the downloadable package and then removed/purged and tried again with `apt-get` and still same error

Comment: The file `/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages` on your system with MD5 of `17ae7853e5273b1730bf4959bc82df5d` possibly has broken dependencies (a different version of the file is currently served by elastic.co, so I could not check). You can verify if this is the case with `grep -B 15 ^Depends:\ filebeat /var/lib/apt/lists/packages.elastic.co_beats_apt_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages`.

Comment: This looks like the downloaded repository metadata defines several versions of the same package, but apt-get doesn't know which one to pick? It's apparent from http://packages.elastic.co/beats/apt/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages and your output that there's a lot of them there (which is uncommon, but not illegal). What happens when you run `apt-get install filebeat=1.2.3` to try to install a specific version?

Comment: The machine is gone :( so couldn't try it